# Android thread suddenly stops

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

In my Android app, there is a thread which handles some heavy work and then updates the UI using handler. However, after start for a while, the thread will stop suddenly without any signal or exception thrown. I do not have any idea of how it happens. Is it a concurrency issue about accessing the same variable by my own thread and UI thread? Below is the code of the thread and handler.

```
TextView textViewFromActivity;
String valueFromThread;

public void startThread() {
    thread.start();
}

public Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if(valueFromThread != null && valueFromThread != "") {
            textViewFromActivity.setText(valueFromThread);
        }
    }
}

public Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            doHeavyWorkAndUpdateValueFromThread();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The following lines displayed on Logcat when the text view stops update.

Logcat:

```
09-20 12:38:32.379: I/Choreographer(32250): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-20 12:38:33.441: I/Choreographer(32250): Skipped 32 frames!  The  application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-20 12:38:34.006: I/Choreographer(32250): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-20 12:38:34.640: I/Choreographer(32250): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-20 12:38:40.496: I/art(32250): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 21.575ms for cause HeapTrim
09-20 12:38:58.146: I/art(32250): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 132986(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free, 16MB/19MB, paused 8.544ms total 42.510ms
09-20 12:39:10.765: I/art(32250): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 8.361ms for cause HeapTrim
09-20 12:39:14.306: I/art(32250): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 125390(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 15MB/19MB, paused 5.645ms total 41.015ms
```

Comment: please post some logcat.

Comment: Posted. The above lines displayed when the text view stops update.

Comment: have you initialized `textViewFromActivity` with `findviewbyid`

Comment: Yes. The text view can be updated initially. After few seconds, only the textview stops responding.

Answer (score 0):

without more information (log output, description of how you're running the app, etc) we can only speculate.

- if your app is undergoing an orientation change, it's possible your thread is now referring to a defunct Handler
- is it possible `doHeavyWorkAndUpdateValueFromThread()` hasn't yet completed?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info for us here to solve the problem, so this will be a pretty generic answer. From what you *have* posted, I would guess that your worker thread actually gets stuck somewhere in normal execution, maybe in a loop or waiting for a server reply...

And here's my generic answer:

Use the debugger. I know it's unfamiliar in the beginning, but learning to use it is *so* worth it.

In this case, you'll be able to see if your thread still lives (add a good name in your thread constructor (like `new Thread("heavy work thread")` to help find the right one), as well as the callstack for its current execution.

You can also pause the thread to inspect current variables and other conditions that may be causing it to loop infinitely.